# Errors while upgrading from Sharepoint 2010 foundation to Sharepoint enterprise

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, upgrade, office, prerequisites

I currently have sharepoint foundation installed and the version number it says is 14.0.4762.1000

I am planning to upgrade to Sharepoint 2010 enterprise.

Before upgrading to sharepoint 2010 enterprise, I completed pre-requisite checker and also installed Office plus 2010 (64 bit).

The server I am planning to install Sharepoint 2010 enterprise is windows 2008 R2 server with SQL 2008Rs (64 bit).

Now I click setup.exe and key-in license key, the progress bar moves for couple of minutes and gives error

"Microsoft sharepoint server 2010  encountered an error during setup". When I check 14 hive and logs folder, I do see some log files but I don't see like any errors and sometimes it makes me think that those log files may not be related to this installation.

How to troubleshoot these log files?  Is the log file location I mentioned correct?

Please suggest how do I proceed?

**Update 1 :** Below is what I found from the log file in TEMP folder.  It talks about registry keys etc but I have logged in as admin and also I launched setup.exe with Run as 'admin'.

MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): DWFolder = C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DW\'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): SETUPINTLDLLDIRECTORY = C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\3\Setup000018a0\'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): LAUNCHEDBYSETUPEXE = 1'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): Manufacturer = Microsoft Corporation'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): ProductCode = {90140000-1015-0409-1000-0000000FF1CE}'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): ProductLanguage = 1033'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): ProductName = Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2010 1033 Lang Pack'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): ProductVersion = 14.0.4763.1000'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): UpgradeCode = {00140000-1015-0000-1000-0000000FF1CE}'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): BUILD = 4750_1000\x64\ship\1033\wssmui'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): DWLANGUAGE = 1033'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): INSTALLLANGUAGE = 1033'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): SetupExeMetadata = PACKAGE.XML_90101504091000;SETUP.XML_90101504091000;BRANDING.XML_1033'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): RequiredOnAllServers = 1'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): emptysource_Ref = emptysource_Ref'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): DISABLEFEATURES = DISABLE_SHAREPOINT_CHECKBOX\'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): product_Ref = product_Ref'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): ProductNameBase = Microsoft Windows SharePoint Services 4.0'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): ProductNameNonQualified = Microsoft Windows SharePoint Services 4.0'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): ProductNameNonQualifiedShort = Microsoft Windows SharePoint Services 4.0'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): ProductNameNonVersioned = Microsoft Windows SharePoint Services 4.0'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): ProductNameQualified = Microsoft Windows SharePoint Services 4.0'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): InstalledByCatalyst_Ref = 0'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): SetARPINSTALLLOCATIONProperty_Ref = 0'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): standardexecuteactions_Ref = standardexecuteactions_Ref'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): SETUPSUPPORTURL = http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=xxxxxx'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): ERRORSUPPORTTEXT_RETAIL_DEFAULT_PROBLEM_PRE = If problem persists, contact Microsoft Product Support Services (PSS) for assistance.  For information about how to contact PSS, see '
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): ERRORSUPPORTTEXT_RETAIL_DEFAULT_PROBLEM_POST = .'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): ERRORSUPPORTTEXT_RETAIL_DEFAULT_PERMISSION_PRE = Verify that you have sufficient permissions to access the registry or contact Microsoft Product Support Services (PSS) for assistance.  For information about how to contact PSS, see '
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): ERRORSUPPORTTEXT_RETAIL_DEFAULT_PERMISSION_POST = .'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): ERRORSUPPORTTEXT_RETAIL_DEFAULT_PRE = Contact Microsoft Product Support Services (PSS) for assistance.  For information about how to contact PSS, see '
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): ERRORSUPPORTTEXT_RETAIL_DEFAULT_POST = .'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): ERRORSUPPORTTEXT_OEM_DEFAULT = Contact your computer manufacturer's product support for assistance.'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): ERRORSUPPORTTEXT_OEM_DEFAULT_PERMISSION = Verify that you have sufficient permissions to access the registry or contact your computer manufacturer's product support for assistance.'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): ERRORSUPPORTTEXT_OEM_DEFAULT_PROBLEM = If problem persists, contact your computer manufacturer's product support for assistance.'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): InstalledByServerCatalyst_Ref = 0'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT = 1'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): NetFrameworkVer = v3.5.21022'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): USINGUIINSTALLMODE = #1'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): SETUPTYPE = CLEAN_INSTALL'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): ALLUSERS = 1'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): SecureCustomProperties = DISABLEFEATURES;DWLANGUAGE;ERRORSUPPORTTEXT;LAUNCHEDBYSETUPEXE;OFFICESERVERSETTINGS;PIDKEY;PIDREPAIR;SETUPHELPFILEDIR;SETUPINTLDLLDIRECTORY;SETUPPSSHELPFILEDIR;SETUPSUPPORTURL'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): MsiHiddenProperties = PIDKEY'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): PackageCode = {36B7350E-C792-4C9F-A91D-2A79948C1147}'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): ProductState = 5'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): ProductToBeRegistered = 1'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): ADDLOCAL = ALL'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): CURRENTDIRECTORY = \tsclient\U\Microsoft\Servers\SharePoint\2010\SharePoint Server 2010\en_sharepoint_server_2010_x64_dvd_518634'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): REBOOT = ReallySuppress'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): MSIRESTARTMANAGERCONTROL = Disable'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): SETUPEXEINSTALLUILANGUAGE = 1033'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): CLIENTUILEVEL = 3'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): MSICLIENTUSESEXTERNALUI = 1'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): CLIENTPROCESSID = 6304'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): PRODUCTLANGUAGE = 1033'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): VersionDatabase = 200'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): VersionMsi = 5.00'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): VersionNT = 601'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): VersionNT64 = 601'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): WindowsBuild = 7600'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): ServicePackLevel = 0'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): ServicePackLevelMinor = 0'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): MsiNTProductType = 2'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): WindowsVolume = C:\'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): System64Folder = C:\Windows\system32\'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): SystemFolder = C:\Windows\SysWOW64\'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): RemoteAdminTS = 1'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): TempFolder = C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): ProgramFilesFolder = C:\Program Files (x86)\'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): CommonFilesFolder = C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): AppDataFolder = C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): FavoritesFolder = C:\Users\Administrator\Favorites\'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): NetHoodFolder = C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts\'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): PersonalFolder = C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): PrintHoodFolder = C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Printer Shortcuts\'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): RecentFolder = C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): SendToFolder = C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo\'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): TemplateFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Templates\'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): CommonAppDataFolder = C:\ProgramData\'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): LocalAppDataFolder = C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): MyPicturesFolder = C:\Users\Administrator\Pictures\'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): AdminToolsFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools\'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): StartupFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): ProgramMenuFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): StartMenuFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): DesktopFolder = C:\Users\Public\Desktop\'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): FontsFolder = C:\Windows\Fonts\'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): GPTSupport = 1'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): OLEAdvtSupport = 1'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): ShellAdvtSupport = 1'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): MsiAMD64 = 6'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): Msix64 = 6'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): Intel = 6'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): PhysicalMemory = 4096'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): VirtualMemory = 4489'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): AdminUser = 1'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): MsiTrueAdminUser = 1'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): LogonUser = administrator'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): UserSID = S-1-5-21-3936247695-3404464505-3220683015-500'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): UserLanguageID = 1033'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): ComputerName = CRMLAB01'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): SystemLanguageID = 1033'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): ScreenX = 1024'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): ScreenY = 768'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): CaptionHeight = 19'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): BorderTop = 1'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): BorderSide = 1'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): TextHeight = 16'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): TextInternalLeading = 3'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): ColorBits = 32'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): TTCSupport = 1'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): Time = 9:46:58'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): Date = 9/12/2012'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): MsiNetAssemblySupport = 4.0.30319.1'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): MsiWin32AssemblySupport = 6.1.7600.16385'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): RedirectedDllSupport = 2'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): MsiRunningElevated = 1'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): Privileged = 1'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): USERNAME = Windows User'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): Installed = 00:00:00'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): DATABASE = C:\Windows\Installer\9aca3.msi'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): OriginalDatabase = C:\Windows\Installer\9aca3.msi'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): UILevel = 2'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): Preselected = 1'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): ACTION = INSTALL'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): ROOTDRIVE = C:\'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): CostingComplete = 1'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): OutOfDiskSpace = 0'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): PrimaryVolumeSpaceAvailable = 0'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): PrimaryVolumeSpaceRequired = 0'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): PrimaryVolumeSpaceRemaining = 0'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): INSTALLLEVEL = 1'
MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): ServicesToRestart = ReportServer=R;SPTIMERV4=R;SPADMINV4=R;SPTRACEV4=R;SPUSERCODEV4=R;'
MSI(INFO): '=== Logging stopped: 9/12/2012  9:46:58 ==='
MSI(COMMONDATA): '1: 2 2: 0 '
MSI(COMMONDATA): '1: 2 2: 1 '
MSI(TERMINATE): ''
Successfully rolled back the configuration of package:

Comment: Why did you install Office on a server?  That is not a requirement.  You may want to take a look at the Application event log for any errors relating to the setup of SharePoint Enterprise.

Comment: I installed office based on recommendatoon from another blog. Don't see any errors in application event log. Has anyone faced similar issue?

Comment: The only place Office belongs is on a workstation or Remote Desktop Server.  SharePoint Server has no dependencies on it, that blog was wrong :)  Do you see anything in the MSI logs?  They should be in %TMP%.

Comment: @TrevorSeward: I found the log and I have updated my original post. Can you please check and let me know?

Comment: Looks like it is a permissions issue.  Also looks like you're running this over an RDP-connected drive.  Can you copy the content of the CD to the local server, and run Setup "As Administrator"?

Comment: I downloaded the software again but this time I ran it as administrator. It is still going without errors. Thanks.. Should I install all Service packs in order (or just Service pack will do?). I guess after all Service packs, it will be CU?

Comment: @TrevorSeward: I want to mark this as answered but don't know if I should tick in this question itself or in a new reply thread.

Comment: For SharePoint Enterprise, first install SharePoint Foundation SP1, then SharePoint Enterprise SP1.

Comment: I already installed SP1 (enterprise). Seems to be working although I will test further. AFter this I was planning to put Aug 2012 CU.